# Create a Second Maria DB on Forge Server for Testing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mariadb, forge

Can someone walk me through the command line steps of booting up another Maria DB instance on a Forge Server that already has one? I am trying to have two instances with two separate credentials...one for testing and another for production.

Comment: You can create new user and new database in same instance. And than if you are using Laravel you simply change .env files as needed.

Comment: @Tim I got it working! thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Nice to hear this. I will put it in an answer for you, so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new user and new database in same instance. And than if you are using Laravel you simply change .env files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a lot simpler than I was making it out to be. I used SequelPro to connect to my Forge instance's MariaDB and simply created a new database (Thanks @Tim for the hint). I changed the testing site's .env to only read / write to the newly created database and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Different "port" *and* directory tree *and* `my.cnf`.

Plan B:  Install in Docker.  And have a different port so you can get to it.

Plan C:  Install in a VM.